# Obsolete entries in svn:mergeinfo

Tags: svn, mergeinfo

I have obsolete entries in my svn:mergeinfo from are already deleted branches.
Is there a way to clean the entries in svn:mergeinfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic way? No, there isn't. But you can do it by hand, either using

```
svn propdel svn:mergeinfo path/to/dir
```

if you want to delete the complete mergeinfo, or

```
svn propedit svn:mergeinfo path/to/dir
```

if you want to change just some lines.

However, I highly recommend that you delete/modify the property only where it really does not make sense. For example, in a typical svn repository layout,

```
/
/trunk
/tags
/tags/t1
/tags/t2...
/branches
/branches/b1
/branches/b2...
```

the `svn:mergeinfo` property should only be set on the trunk node and the branch root nodes (i.e. /branches/b1 etc.). If you never merge between anything else but the trunk and the branch root nodes, you can usually safely delete all mergeinfo properties on other files.

A final note: if the only place where svn:mergeinfo is bothering you is trunk, that stop here and now. It is just too much of a hassle with too little gain :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The svn:mergeinfo only exists on my /trunk and /branches/*/ Root-Nodes. I just realized two old entries in svn:mergeinfo (on both trunk and branches Root-Nodes) from very old braches and asked myself if I should delete these entries or not. But if these entries aren't of any problem, then I can safely ignore this.
Thanks

Comment: In that case just leave it as it is. This is exactly how it is supposed to be, and you don't gain anything by fiddling around with `svn:mergeinfo`. Really, the only reason to change anything manually is when one of your users merged where he shouldn't have... but it seems like your repo is in good shape.